# Bypass root password in linux live boot customized Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

I have a laptop on which i have Ubuntu running.
This Ubuntu is on live boot and it is customized by the school.
Whenever I turn on my laptop, it automatically logs me in as user TIPS.
This user doesn't have root perms.
Is there any way I can bypass that, or get the root password somehow??
It makes it a 100 times harder since it is live boot :( .
Even if I start up a root shell in boot and reset root password, it gets reset when i reboot it to update changes.
By The way, the laptop is mine.
It just has the school OS.

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT** : Is it possible to configure `/cdrom` of the live boot to delete the password file? I could do it with a live cd of another OS.

Comment: I think they don't want you to do that.

Comment: I guess so.....

Comment: You need to ask the owner of the (operating) system. Any help circumventing passwords is basically illegal in my country nowadays.

Comment: By the way. I have tried so many methods. Is there any way to edit the live boot files? like the `/cdrom` dir??

Comment: BTW its my laptop with the school's OS

Comment: I would have to think hard about allowing anybody, particularly most University IT staffs that I've dealt with, to put an OS on my laptop. This is despite (or because of) that fact that I've been University IT staff at two different universities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason that you are using the school's OS on your personal machine? There's probably a number of ways around your problem. If you only need to use it occasionally for a specific reason, I would suggest using either a virtual machine or setting up a dual boot system. If you don't actually need it, then just install your own OS and call it a day.